# Sending array of nulls in json request - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to send request to my Rails API with key like: `ids: [null, 1, 2, null, 3]`. Unfortunately Rails cuts all the nulls from this array so the `params[:ids]` returns `[1, 2, 3]`. I need those nulls in the array.

How can I prevent Rails from removing them? I can send empty string instead of null, but it's not very elegant.

Comment: What do you mean by Rails cuts all the nulls from this array?? As per my knowledge by default rails doesn't have any feature like this.

Comment: Please share your code, whether r u using array compact method?, Describe more to get understand.

Answer (score 6):

In rails 5, intends to not have the same sql injection vulnerabilities and so have removed the deep_munge method that would change an empty array value to nil but have left in the configuration option which produces behavior best described by looking at the tests.

for more info

https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionDispatch/Request/deep_munge

https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/e1bed09363-deepmunge-i-hardly-knew-ye

In application.rb add below line

```
config.action_dispatch.perform_deep_munge = false
```

and restart the application

Answer (score 1):

**use json structure instead of array**

replace

> ids: [null, 1, 2, null, 3]

with

> ids: {"0": null, "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": null, "4": 3}

**And in controller access it like**

```
params[:ids].values
[nil, 1, 2, nil, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

In different environment `null` value is interpreted differently.

I think that the best practice is to replace these entries according the result you want to achieve:

```
ids.map! { |id| id == null ? nullValue : id }.flatten!
```

Where `nullValue` is what you're expecting to have in the array.